# Cannot set window.location.href to a hash after 302 response

Tags: jquery, hashchange

I am attempting to set the URL fragment upon page load for a AJAX-controlled Django webapp, similar to a page redirect.

The intended behavior is: if a user loads `myapp.com`, I change the fragment to `myapp.com/#/default/path`, which triggers a content change.

Current implementation with jQuery is as follows:

```
if (!window.location.hash) {
    window.location.href = (window.location.pathname === "/")
        ? $("html").data("default-hash")
        : hashify(window.location.pathname);
} else {
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
}
```

In this case, the default fragment is included as a data-* attribute in `<html>`, and `hashify()` is a function that prepends `/#` to a string. I want to be able to simply return a 302 redirect from the server, and then convert the pathname to a hash as follows:

```
if (!window.location.hash) {
    window.location.href = hashify(window.location.pathname);
} else {
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
}
```

In the current implementation, the url changes per the expected behavior. But when I try the second method (with the redirect), the URI ends up being `myapp.com/default/path/#/default/path`.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before, or has any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks!